# javascript function for HTML manipulation not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

This js code is supposed to change the the value of class attribute 'skills__open' to 'skills__close' when the 'skills__header' div is clicked. It changes the  'skills__open' to  'skills__close' on the first click, but after the first click, it is not working.

Js

```
const skillsContent = document.getElementsByClassName('skills__content'),
      skillsHeader = document.querySelectorAll('.skills__header')

function toggleSkills(){ 
    let itemClass = this.parentNode.ClassName
    for(i=0; i < skillsContent.length; i++){
        skillsContent[i].className = 'skills__content skills__close'
    }
    if(itemClass === 'skills__content skills__close'){
        this.parentNode.className = 'skills__content skills__open'
    } 
}
skillsHeader.forEach((el) =>{
    el.addEventListener('click', toggleSkills)
});
```

Html

```
<div class="skills__content skills__open">
   <div class="skills__header">
</div>
<div class="skills__content skills__close">
    <div class="skills__header">
</div>
<div class="skills__content skills__close">
    <div class="skills__header">
</div>
```

css

```
.skills__open .skills__list{
  height: max-content;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2-5);
}
.skills__open .skills__arrow{
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

nothing significant

Comment: Well, `this.parentNode.ClassName` should be `this.parentNode.className`. But I would use the `classList` interface instead.

Comment: I notice the HTML could either be invalid (missing `</div>`) or has a nested structure, and that might be a factor. Suggestions: replace your sample with a live code snippet that shows the issue, also check out `Element.classList` (add remove, toggle, replace methods): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList.

Comment: Try scoping `i` to the for loop in which its declared. `for (let i = 0)`

Comment: it is useless to use 2 classes (open and close) if your elements can only have these 2 possible states.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
const skillsContents = document.querySelectorAll('.skills__content');

skillsContents.forEach( skc =>
  {
  skc
  .querySelector('.skills__header')
  .addEventListener('click', () =>
    {
    skillsContents.forEach( el =>
      {
      if (skc===el) el.classList.replace('skills__close','skills__open')
      else          el.classList.replace('skills__open','skills__close')
      })
    })
  });
```